# Theme upload fails

Tags: uploads

I upload a new theme from .zip folder and it says that it is uploading then when it reaches 100% the page reloads and asks 'do you want to do this?' and my only option is to 'try again'.

how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This is cleary a `max_upload` issue. You are trying to upload a theme with a size bigger then the size allowed. In this case you have two solutions:

1) Use FTP in order to upload you new theme. You got to **wp_content\themes** and you upload the **unzipped** folder there. You will then find it in the dashboard.

2) You increase the maximum upload size and you try again. For this you have a lot of lot of possibily, you may read [this to learn how](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/).